# filter dataframe using isna() to filter ourt rows that have null value in following columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have dataframe similar to this one:

```
     id     name    val1_rain   val2_tik    val3_bon   val4_tig ...
0   2349    Rivi    0.11       0.34            0.78       0.21
1   3397    Mani    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN
2   0835    Pigi    0.34       NaN             0.32       NaN
3   5093    Tari    0.65       0.12            0.34       2.45
4   2340    Yoti    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN
```

I want to drop any row that has all null values for all the columns that come after the name column ( [:,2:]).
So the result output would look like this:

```
     id     name    val1_rain   val2_tik    val3_bon   val4_tig ...
0   2349    Rivi    0.11       0.34            0.78       0.21
2   0835    Pigi    0.34       NaN             0.32       NaN
3   5093    Tari    0.65       0.12            0.34       2.45
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
df[~df.iloc[:,2:].isnull()]
```

but that raised an error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

First of all, I'm not sure why the error speaks about duplicate axis.

Then, **I would like to find a way that I can have only rows that have any value at any column after the 2nd column.**

I haven't found any question similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter if exist at least one non missing values after second columns with [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df = df[df.iloc[:,2:].notna().any(axis=1)]
print (df)
     id  name  val1_rain  val2_tik  val3_bon  val4_tig
0  2349  Rivi       0.11      0.34      0.78      0.21
2   835  Pigi       0.34       NaN      0.32       NaN
3  5093  Tari       0.65      0.12      0.34      2.45
```